# import a function from an other file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, python-import

I know that this question has already been asked. But answers below these questions doesn't fix my problem. Here it is:

When I download some code from GitHub, it's always divided into separate files. I understand that it's important to have organized code, which is why I'd like to do the same.

However, whenever I try importing a function from a file, I always seem to get a `ModuleNotFoundError` error.

The file that I'm trying to import is in the same directory as the file importing the code. This also doesn't work with other code, for example, when I download code from GitHub that organizes code using separate files, it still returns the same error.

I've tried two different python installations (anaconda 3.7.3 and py 3.7.0), but still not luck. FYI I use `pzyo` to run my files.

Here's an example of how I import another file:
`from fun import f`

I have tried this as well:

```
import os
os.chdir("C:/Users/amau4/Desktop/test")
from fon import f
```

How would I go about fixing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not about CWD at time of import, but `PYTHONPATH` at start resp. `sys.path` at the time of import. I.e. for instance `sys.path.append("C:/Users/amau4/Desktop/test")` would tell your interpreter to look for `fon` also in that directory.

Comment: @OndrejK. Thank you, so if I replace `os.chdir("path")` `sys.path.append("C:/Users/amau4/Desktop/test")` It would work ? or I need something else ? Because it doesn't seem to work